# Sinatra and Datamapper not able to save an array to the datatype Object

Tags: ruby, arrays, object, sinatra, datamapper

I have an HTML form which uses the following Sinatra code to handle POST for the url '/add-artist':

```
post '/add-artist' do
  if logged_in?
    a = Artist.new
    a.name = params[:name]
    a.website = params[:website]
    a.facebook = params[:facebook]
    a.created_by = session[:user_id]
    a.created_at = Time.now
    a.updated_by = session[:user_id]
    a_updated_at = Time.now
    a.views = 0
    a.save
    @user = User.get session[:user_id]
    @user.artists.push(a.id)
    @user.save
    redirect '/'
  end
end
```

The object 'a' is being saved but '@user' is not. I guess more specifically, the value '@user.artists' is not being updated. If you need more info, please ask but I have a feeling that you Ruby vets will find the problem in the code I provided.

UPDATE

Here's some additional info. I was able to reproduce the error in irb. First here's my class definition for 'User'.

```
# dm_models.rb
require 'data_mapper'

DataMapper::setup(:default, "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/event_review.db") 

class User
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :email, String
  property :password, String
  property :user_name, String
  property :birthdate, Date
  property :city, String
  property :state, String
  property :zip, String
  property :geodata, Object
  property :bio, Text
  property :friends, Object
  property :events, Object
  property :event_reviews, Integer
  property :artists, Object
  property :artist_reviews, Integer
  property :venues, Object
  property :venue_reviews, Integer
  property :created_at, DateTime
  property :updated_at, DateTime
  property :views, Integer

  has n, :reviews

end
```

Here is the irb

```
>> require 'sinatra'
=> true
>> require 'data_mapper'
=> true
>> require './models/dm_models.rb'
=> true
>> require 'geokit'
=> true
>> 
?> include Geokit::Geocoders
=> Object
>> u = User.get 8
=> #<User @id=8 @email="km@km.com" @password="km" @user_name="Katherine Miller" @birthdate=#<Date: 4895485/2,0,2299161> @city="Burbank" @state="CA" @zip="91501" @geodata=#<Geokit::GeoLoc:0x10150d4d8 @street_number=nil, @suggested_bounds=#<Geokit::Bounds:0x10150cf88 @sw=#<Geokit::LatLng:0x10150cd80 @lng=-118.315043, @lat=34.1766949>, @ne=#<Geokit::LatLng:0x10150cee8 @lng=-118.27996, @lat=34.221666>>, @lng=-118.2935891, @zip="91501", @state="CA", @precision="zip", @province=nil, @all=[#<Geokit::GeoLoc:0x10150d4d8 ...>], @street_address=nil, @provider="google", @city="Burbank", @lat=34.2039087, @country_code="US", @full_address="Burbank, CA 91501, USA", @street_name=nil, @accuracy=5, @country="USA", @success=true> @bio=<not loaded> @friends=[] @events=["13", "14", "15", "16", "28", "29"] @event_reviews=7 @artists=[] @artist_reviews=1 @venues=[] @venue_reviews=0 @created_at=#<DateTime: 70729968253/28800,-5/24,2299161> @updated_at=#<DateTime: 1178838019/480,-5/24,2299161> @views=56>
>> 
?> u.artists
=> []
>> u.artists.push "5"
=> ["5"]
>> u.save
=> true
>> u = User.get 8
=> #<User @id=8 @email="km@km.com" @password="km" @user_name="Katherine Miller" @birthdate=#<Date: 4895485/2,0,2299161> @city="Burbank" @state="CA" @zip="91501" @geodata=#<Geokit::GeoLoc:0x1014e8638 @street_number=nil, @suggested_bounds=#<Geokit::Bounds:0x1014e80e8 @sw=#<Geokit::LatLng:0x1014e7eb8 @lng=-118.315043, @lat=34.1766949>, @ne=#<Geokit::LatLng:0x1014e8048 @lng=-118.27996, @lat=34.221666>>, @lng=-118.2935891, @zip="91501", @state="CA", @precision="zip", @province=nil, @all=[#<Geokit::GeoLoc:0x1014e8638 ...>], @street_address=nil, @provider="google", @city="Burbank", @lat=34.2039087, @country_code="US", @full_address="Burbank, CA 91501, USA", @street_name=nil, @accuracy=5, @country="USA", @success=true> @bio=<not loaded> @friends=[] @events=["13", "14", "15", "16", "28", "29"] @event_reviews=7 @artists=[] @artist_reviews=1 @venues=[] @venue_reviews=0 @created_at=#<DateTime: 70729968253/28800,-5/24,2299161> @updated_at=#<DateTime: 1178838019/480,-5/24,2299161> @views=56>
>> u.artists
=> []
>> u.artists.class
=> Array
```

The description of the above code: I retrieve user with id==8, push the value "5" into it. This appears to be successful. I save user#8. Then I re-retrieve user#8 and look at the artists value and it is an empty array.

And finally, I am able to update other fields like "artist_reviews". Is this because I am defining the datatype to be 'Object' for artists, events and venues? This problem exists for all of those fields.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this a while ago but I'm pretty certain the solution is to serialize the object. In this case it was an array of integers. I'm not sure if I'll have the time to update this with a detailed solution but an array cannot be stored directly in a relational database. The array object must be 'serialized', essentially converted to a string. In this example the datatype for the `artist` attribute would then be `text.`

You could manually convert the artist column to an array (from string) push the new integer(s) into the array and then convert back to string and save. I'm assuming there is an automated way to do this but that's the idea.

Furthermore, this entire example is a poor way to handle associations. The better way to do this is to have a one-to-many association where there is an `ArtistUser` table which has two columns `artist_id` and `user_id`. Every new association is represented as a new row in the `ArtistUser` table.

Answer (score 0):

What do the logs say? Can you push to @user.artists? Is it an Array? It might fail validation and you cannot complete save.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the error in irb, so it should be easier to figure out. I'll edit my question with that information.

Comment: why do you need Object for artists? It seems like you want an Array and you can't push "5" into Object. I assume that if you choose Object you will have to use artist= which will then marshal the object into that property.

Comment: Full disclosure, I've only been using Ruby for about a month, so I don't have a great reason for using the datatype "Object." I didn't see anything in the datamapper documentation for using an Array datatype, so I guessed that in Ruby an Array is an Object, so it might work. And it actually has, strangely, up to this point. I think I am just going to change my approach to the problem I'm trying to solve instead of continuing to bang my head against this. I think using the "has_n" and "belongs_to" associations I will be able to get what I need accomplished.